# Horizontal scroll doesn't work on Mouse

Tags: gnome, mouse, input-devices, mouse-scroll

I have a mouse which has left and right scroll. The scroll works fine in 16.04 GNOME, but not working in 18.04 with GNOME.

I've read these answers:

[Inverted Horizontal scrolling ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029128/inverted-horizontal-scrolling-ubuntu-18-04)

[Horizontal Scrolling checked but still doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103727/horizontal-scrolling-checked-but-still-doesnt-work)

but they are related to the touchpad not mouse.

Searched for settings in dconf-editor for Horizontal scroll but didn't find anything:

[image: dconf-editor mouse settings]

How can I enable horizontal scroll for my mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the mouse scroll if your mouse is [supported](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/tree/master/data/devices) in libratbag:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libratbag-piper/piper-libratbag-git
sudo apt update
sudo apt install piper
```

[image: Piper Mouse]

You can also configure RGB and DPI in Piper.