# Horizontal Scroll with Mouse does not work on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, scrolling, input-devices, libinput

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and I have logitech G500 mouse with a scroll button in the middle.

My goal is to do horizontal scrolling by tilting the scroll button left and right. I was able to do this on `ubuntu 16.04`. But after updating to `18.04`, it seems that this feature no longer work.

I followed the opposite of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/308815/disable-mouse-horizontal-scrolling-on-linux) solution, which is:

```
xinput list
xinput test 9 #as my mouse's ID is 9
xinput set-button-map 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

This enables me to scroll to the `left` by tilting the scroll button to the left, but tilting it to the right does not do anything. Also, after this, dragging the scroll button able to drag around the window.

I looked at solution [Horizontal scroll doesn't work on Mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119145/horizontal-scroll-doesnt-work-on-mouse/1222594#1222594)

but still did not work. Therefore, this question is not a duplicate of above.

I use `libinput` as an input driver, and `unity` for desktop.